# Retrieve Django media files from render.com disk

Tags: python, django, deployment, web-deployment

I'm deploying my Django application via [render.com](http://render.com/) and I'm using a disk to serve the media files uploaded by the user. I can tell that the media files *are* being uploaded to the right place by using the render.com shell:

[Image files appear in the media folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMbCI.png)

However, when I try retrieving the image files in my website template, they don't appear.

[Images aren't appearing on the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvoM7.png)

My MEDIA_ROOT is "/var/www/[mysite].onrender.com/media/" ([mysite] replaced with the application name) and my MEDIA_URL is '/media/'. On render, the mount path of my disk is '/opt/render/project/src/media/'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just got it working, actually! Added this to my urls.py:

```
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    }),
]
```

Comment: Hey, what was the actual path? My disk is mounted under `/var/disk/`, I upload files under `var/disk/kurak/uploads/`. What path should I place in the `img src="?"` ‍♂️ Can you help @cyborg48?